# Textures getting darker when inside of a cube

Tags: texturing, light, normals

I'm using Blender 2.79 and Cycles render. For some reason the textures get darker from the half to the top of the cube, even with the normals facing the right direction (inside). The light source is just a point lamp but also don't work with a sun lamp or HDR (there is a window in the room), the materials works well when outside the cube.

[image: Dark texture at the top of the image]

By flipping the top part (facing outside) the problem is "fixed" but poorly

[image: Flipped normals]

Comment: What render engine? What blender version?

Comment: Additionally, what's your lighting source? It looks terribly, exactly like a shadow (perhaps from a wide, soft Spot or angled Area light). A closed Cube wouldn't allow any Environment lighting inside if there were no openings or too small openings without a portal-instructed Area light to help out.

Comment: It's hard to tell what is going on without any information on how the scene is lit.

Comment: @Jackdaw Blender 2.79, Cycles render.

Comment: @HelloHiHola It's just a temporary point light in the center of the cube, even with a sun light trought a window doesn't change that.

Comment: @cegaton It's just a temporary point light in the center of the cube.

Comment: Can you post more follow up? How are you distributing textures across faces? Have you tried the material on another object? What IS the UV unwrap you've done? What is your Node Setup? There's just not enough to go on yet.

Comment: Humm, maybe it could be normal maps that are not using the "non-color data" option on the texture node. Hard to investigate without the file.

Comment: @HelloHiHola The materials works well, UV and nodes looks alright, the problem apparently is with the normals, I updated the post by the way.

Comment: @Jackdaw Everything except the diffuse is using non-color data.

Comment: I'm really interested in helping but would need .blend file access or that Node screenshot. The flip you did changed the scale of the texture too along the object Z from what I can see. I'm beginning to think this is a Vector or mapping error of a texture that has a gradient built in. Can you share an image of the full texture/s? And thanks for the Q updates! :)

Comment: @JoãoVitorSchiavon please add here your blend file to see whats going on... https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @HelloHiHola The nodes are all like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZq1o.jpg 

The normal map is set to "object space" otherwise would be all dark. The textures are from Poliigon and Texture Haven and they work in other circunstances, I apreciate your effort in helping me.

Comment: It's very suspicious to have 15x15y scales on Point. Another couple setting that stood out were Normal Map and Bump's Strength set to 1.0. That's highly unusual because the results get bad quickly. Personally, I've never reset the Normals with Normal Map the way you did. I tried it and it really redirects the facing severely. Can you adjust it or live without it but still keep the Bump Height? My "Normal" experiments produce black distortions but not quite like yours.

Comment: @HelloHiHola The texture is very big that's why is 15x15.
What's the problem with the strength set to 1?
The problem persist without the normal map.